Installation of Tutor edx palm version on AWS EKS
I'm in the process of upgrading to the Tutor Open edX Palm version and I'm planning to deploy it on a Kubernetes cluster, specifically using AWS EKS. I would appreciate any advice or best practices for this setup.
Key Points:

Environment: AWS EKS (Elastic Kubernetes Service)
Current Version: Upgrading from Koa to Palm
Requirements:

Setting up a scalable and resilient environment.
Handling persistent storage for MongoDB, MySQL, and other services.
Best practices for configuring autoscaling and resource allocation.
Recommendations for monitoring and logging within Kubernetes.
Security considerations, especially with AWS-specific tools like IAM roles and security groups.



If anyone has successfully set up Tutor Open edX Palm on Kubernetes or AWS EKS, I would love to hear about your experiences, any documentation you followed, or specific configurations that worked well.
Tried with installation if Tutor Palm version but getting errors. Use Tutor documentation for k8s installation. [Tutor edx] (https://docs.tutor.edly.io/k8s.html)
